# How to get previous div on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using two anchor tags: "previous-slide-collections" and "next-slide-collections". Next anchor works while previous does not.

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#next-slide-collections").click((function(){
        //alert('hi');
    var counter = 0;
    return function()
    {
       $("#div" + counter).hide("fast");
       counter = (counter % 3) + 1;
       $("#div" + counter).show("fast");
    }
 })());

$("#previous-slide-collections").click((function(){
    //alert('hi');
    var counter = 0;
    return function()
    {
       $("#div" + counter).hide("fast");
       counter = (counter - 1);
       $("#div" + counter).show("fast");
    }
})());
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<a id="previous-slide-collections"></a>
<a id="next-slide-collections"></a>
```

Comment: Where the code relates to `previous-slide-collections`?

Comment: Just looking at existing logic, your previous slide collections button won't be in sync with your next slide collections button since they each will get their own counter var. with that in mind, if your previous button also starts with counter at 0, there will never be a previous.

Comment: Your code is only set to get next.  There's ntohing set to wire previous.  `$("#next-slide-collections, #previous-slide-collections")` would target both next and previous.  I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: next is working fine but previous anchor tag is not working..

Comment: @RohitKhurana You already stated that in your question... we're telling you ***Why*** it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your next and previous buttons each use their own counter variable. Your next button should work, however, since your previous button's counter starts at 0, clicking it will go to -1 which will select 0 elements. To confirm, change your previous counter to start at 3 and you'll see it do something.

Make them share the same variable and it should work (mostly).

```
var counter = 0;
$("#next-slide-collections").click(function()
    {
       $("#div" + counter).hide("fast");
       counter = (counter % 3) + 1;
       $("#div" + counter).show("fast");
    }
);

$("#previous-slide-collections").click(function()
    {
       $("#div" + counter).hide("fast");
       counter = (counter - 1);
       $("#div" + counter).show("fast");
    }
);
```

you still have to account for clicking prevous when it's on the first div and next when it's on the last.

Comment: Is this possible is a horrible way of asking anything related to programming. Almost everything is possible in one way or another.

Comment: Just add an if statement to both events that changes the value if it reaches either end.